# How to get get weekly returns from daily data

Tags: programming, asset-returns

Good day

I would like to get weekly returns data from daily data , I want to use the Wednesday-to-Wednesday approach – the returns (rt) are computed from the Wednesday closing prices Pt
, i.e., rt = ln(Pt/Pt-1). In the cases in which Wednesdays were not active trading days, the closing values from the next date with valid prices from the sequence of the nearest days is used:
I'm Stata user as well as an excel user

Any hint will be highly appreciated!! 
thaks!!

Comment: consider the following YouTube video I made on how to change time intervals. You would just have to tweek it a bit to get desired Wednesday to Wednesday dates. http://youtu.be/SHVN-AyU0jk @ama

Comment: @Rim thank you Rim, It worked great for one company,my issue is that I have thousand of company and I have to repeat that action a thousand of time!!

Comment: Oh I see. I do not know Stata but I believe there are methods to do this using R-code for various iterations @Ama

Comment: Ama,
Is your issue getting a data set with all the symbols/history you require? If you are familiar with PQ/PP, I'll work up an Excel solution for you. Let me know. Thanks. Jason,
A simple but elegant approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Nin sute, thank you very much for your help yes sure I would be very grateful if you helped me out with that!!

Answer (score 2):

You can compute daily gross returns and then simply multiply them:
$R_w=\prod_i \left(1+R_i \right)-1$, where $R_i=P_{close,i}/P_{close,i-1}-1$

Comment: If you do some analytics you will figure out that 
$R_w=P_{close,the-last-day-of-the-week}/P_{close,the-last-day-before-the-week}$
 So, there are much less computations